# get methods return undefined in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I don't undertand what's my code error when defining the get and set methods for a private field.

```
export class User{
  private userName = "defaultName";

  constructor(private token:string){}

  public get UserName():string{
    return this.userName;
  }

  public set UserName(value:string){
    this.userName = value;
  }    

  public get Token():string{
    return this.token;
  }

  public set Token(value:string){
    this.token= value;
  }
}
```

When I try the following code I get undefined values.

```
    const user:User = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
    console.log(user.UserName);
    console.log(user.Token);
```

**EDIT**

**The problem is not about the get methods**. I tried to read fields of a custom object (User) using data retrieved from localStorage:

```
 const user:User = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
```

With that code I'm able to read public fields but not the private ones using the get methods, because when you `JSON.parse` data (in my case retrieved from `localStorage`) you obtain a plain javascript object, even if you try to "typify" the variable this way: `user:User`.

I tried to access the field using the get method `user.UserName` that actually doens't exist on the plain javascript object I created with JSON.parse; inside this plain javascript object there is only the field user.username. What I tried to do is not possible (I suppose).

Comment: What is `user`? Please make this a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @kaya3,  I edited the code

Comment: Can you share with a result or error? On create example on https://stackblitz.com/?
I don't quite get it

Comment: This isn't a "reproducible" example, because it depends on what's in your local storage, which will not be there for answerers trying to reproduce the issue on our own machines. Does the issue actually depend on using local storage?

Comment: Hi guys, I edited my post explaining why I can't do what I tried to do, becuase it was "illogical"

Comment: I updated my answer I think it should help now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code should work. [Playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-wbdeen)

Why didn't your example work out?

When you parse item from local storage `user` variable becomes something like this:
`{ userName: "John", token: 30 }`

But you accessing `user.UserName` which does not exists so you have to mimic object from `localStorage` like so `user.userName`.

Ways to fix it:

1. Create new instance of the `User` class

```js
const userFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ userName: "John", token: 30 }));
const user = new User(userFromLocalStorage.userName, userFromLocalStorage.token)
console.log(user.userName);
console.log(user.token);
```

2. Create getters/setters that mimic shape of object like in example below

Things to consider.

- In typescript we don't write capitalized setters or getters
- Use this approach for naming private variables `private _userName = "defaultName";` with underscore
- Doing this `constructor(public token:string){}` you don't have to create setters or getters.

```js
export class User{
  private _userName = "defaultName";

  constructor(username, public token:string){
    this.userName = username;
  }

  public get userName():string{
    return this._userName;
  }

  public set userName(value:string){
    this._userName = value;
  }    
}
const user: User = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ "userName":"John", "token":30 }))
console.log(user.userName);
console.log(user.token);
```

[Typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html)

Comment: Hi @Yuriy, thanks for you advice, I'll follow it. I edited the code, the problem seems to be another .